# Selenium error: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: python, selenium, dom, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I am trying to get a list of proxies from https://sslproxies.org/ using Selenium (headless via PhantomJS) and BeautifulSoup:

This is what I did so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://sslproxies.org/")

while True:
    try:
        next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='paginate_button next'][@id='proxylisttable_next']")
    
    except:
        break
    next_button.click()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(next_button.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'html.parser')
```

But I get this error:

```
"errorMessage":"Element is no longer attached to the DOM"
```

Comment: I solved it with `for` loop but in a current condition it does not scrape just the last page, gets 80 results. I can post it you will solve how to scrape the last page by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `next_button`, then clicking said button, then trying to reference the `next_button` variable again. Your click has caused you to navigate to another page with a brand new DOM, and your definition for `next_button` no longer works. To avoid this you can simply redefine the variable or just always use the whole

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='paginate_button next'][@id='proxylisttable_next']")
```

Answer (score 1):

1 You can iterate through pages using `for` loop, but for this you will need to get the number of pages. Depending on site getting the number of pages method may be different. In you case it is ease.
You get the length of pages locators list+1, like this: `len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='paginate_button ']"))`.

2 Your locator was incorrect, so I changed it to: `//li[@class='paginate_button next'][@id='proxylisttable_next']/a`  (added `/a`)

3 After finding the button you click it in `finally`.

**SOLUTION**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://sslproxies.org/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='paginate_button ']"))
print(f"List length is: {length}")
for j in range(1, length+1):
    try:
        print("Clicking Page " + str(j+1))
        wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section[id='list']")))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='paginate_button next'][@id='proxylisttable_next']/a")))
    finally:
        next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//li[@class='paginate_button next'][@id='proxylisttable_next']/a")
        next_button.click()
```

P.S. I tested it on Chrome, but it should work in any browser, as I use stable locators and waits.

My output for debug:

```
List length is: 4
Clicking Page 2
Clicking Page 3
Clicking Page 4
Clicking Page 5
```